# A way to make as.Date a bit more careful with formats

Tags: r, date

I Just found out that R's `as.Date` is a very forgiving function.

Here is a simple dataset of start/end days:

```
df <- data.frame(start = c("02-03-2020","04-05-2020", "06-01-2002", "13-09-2020"), 
                 end = c("12-07-2020","04-06-2020", "26-02-2020", "11-10-2020"))
```

I've got a code who parsed it as follows:

```
df %>% mutate_all(function(x) as.Date(x = x, format = "%d-%m-%y"))
#       start        end
#1 2020-03-02 2020-07-12
#2 2020-05-04 2020-06-04
#3 2020-01-06 2020-02-26
#4 2020-09-13 2020-10-11
```

No warnings at all, data look nice, but as you can see there is a typo in the format argument. It should be a full 4 digits year `%Y`: `%d-%m-%Y`. Nonetheless, `as.Date` doesn't see a problem and takes the first two digits from the year number.

My question is: Do you know of any way to prevent such mistakes? Is there a way to force `as.Date` to control the full compatibility of arguments and the specified format, so that I can notice that I made this typo in the moment of the function execution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting question! After some googling, it seems like `readr::parse_date` does what you want: `df %>% mutate_all(function(x) readr::parse_date(x = as.character(x), format = "%d-%m-%y"))` gives NAs and a warning: `Warning: 4 parsing failures.` From its [documentation](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/parse_datetime.html): "Unlike strptime(), the format specification must match the complete string.".

Comment: Nice! Thank you! Probably I've done too little of googling. However, I think that `as.Date` by its definition should be leaving at least the warning that *is trying* to convert despite the difference between the given and the expected format.

Comment: Not sure about that, I think it's the responsibility of the user to provide an accurate format. It's also [intentional](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strptime): "Each input string is processed as far as necessary for the format specified: any trailing characters are ignored."